# How to bind / call / pass 'this' to mousemove function

Tags: javascript

I'm working on being able to `mousedown` on a card element and then moving that card with `mousemove`.

I have my variables at the top, followed by functions, followed be event listeners:

```
// variables


// selector for elements with class .card
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

// variable containing x and y coordinates of mouse
var mousePosition;

// boolean to track if mouse is down
var isDown = false;



// functions


// function for mousedown on .card
function cardHold() {

  // set isDown to true
  isDown = true;

  this.style.boxShadow = '0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22)';

 }


// function for mouseup on .card
function cardRelease() {

  // set isDown to false
  isDown = false;

  this.style.boxShadow = '0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23)';

}

// function for mousedown & move on .card
function mouseMove() {

  if (isDown) {

    mousePosition = {

      x : event.clientX,
      y : event.clientY

    };

    // this.style.left = (mousePosition.x + 'px');
    // this.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + 'px');

  }

}


// event listeners

// loop through elements with class .card and attach event listeners for mousedown and mouseup
for (var index = 0; index < cards.length; index++) {

  cards[index].addEventListener('mousedown', cardHold);
  cards[index].addEventListener('mouseup', cardRelease);

}

// attach an event listener on the document to track mousemove
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

The usage of `this` within the `cardHold` and `cardRelease` functions are working, but the usage of `this` within `mouseMove` is wrong.

The event listener at the very bottom line calls the `mouseMove` function:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

In the `mouseMove` function, I tried this:

```
    // this.style.left = (mousePosition.x + 'px');
    // this.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + 'px');
```

..which is where I attempted to move the card by restyling `this`, but `mouseMove` is passing the `document` object as `this` here, which I realized by checking `console.log(this)` within the `mouseMove` function.

I think I need to use `bind` or `apply` or `call` here to somehow pass the `this` value from the `cardHold` function to the `mouseMove` function, but I'm unable to figure out the correct syntax here, or which one of these three to use.

Something like:

```
this.bind(mouseMove);
```

...at the beginning of the `mouseDown` function, but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Were you aware that there are specific _drag_ events for this sort of thing ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: You may find the following question and its answers illuminating: [Use of the JavaScript 'bind' method](//stackoverflow.com/q/2236747)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Definitely checked out that one and was having difficulty wrapping my head around it as it relates to my problem, but I'll continue to look through it and try to figure it out

Comment: Let's try mouseMove.bind(this)

Comment: Your issue is that `mouseMove` is bound to the `document`.

Comment: @Phil do you think drag is the best option in this case?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I thought `this` would be the card element within `mouseMove` since its event listener is on the document, but don't really know how to reassign `this` within that function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a variable to store `this` within the `cardHold` function:

```
function cardHold() {

  // store this within variable
  movingCard = this;

  // set isDown to true
  isDown = true;
  console.log(isDown);

  this.style.boxShadow = '0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22)';

}
```

And then I can access `movingCard` and move it within the `mouseMove` function:

```
// function for mousedown & move on .card
function mouseMove() {

  if (isDown) {

    mousePosition = {

          x : event.clientX,
          y : event.clientY

      };

       movingCard.style.left = (mousePosition.x) + 'px';
       movingCard.style.top  = (mousePosition.y) + 'px';

  }

}
```

While that does seem to work, I sort of feel like there must be a better solution to this and will mark someone else's answer correct if they can help.